# Chrome problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I have a few annoying problems.
The thing is, that when I am looking with Firefox every thing work perfect, after I try it with Chrome, sometimes happens that the code appears one web page (it is not all the time).

So, it appears in input text it display " />" or some piece of code of java script, which is written inside input tag.

The web page is: www.kalahoo.eu (do not try it in English )

In this picture you can see the problem:

http://rhc.si/slike/problem.png

Thank you very much for you help!!!

Comment: Like Sage asked post direct link might help. My first guess is a missing quote, firefox perhaps is ignoring it etc...

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome here too. What version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to the exact page with this error?

Either way, I would imagine that if you use the Chrome developer tools, you should get pointed in the right direction. Might want to give that a try.

Comment: For responses like this, please add it as a comment rather than an answer so it doesn't clutter up the answers. Thank you!

Comment: I can comment on this though, just not on the original question. How much rep to comment?

Comment: I believe 10. @chelmertz - That does bring up a good point...should people with rep less than 10 just not ask follow-up questions until they have the rep? (Either way, it's very easy to get to.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be improperly escaping code that's making the HTML end before the rest of the attributes are read.
Check the spot in the code where its doing that, its probably a bad ' or " or even a `>`.